# PowerShell output running processes properties to a text file and output the properties' count to console

Tags: powershell-2.0

I need to output the list of properties returned by the Get-Process cmdlet to a text file  and print the properties' count to the console. My first idea was:

```
Get-Process | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Out-File -FilePath C:\Process.txt -Encoding ASCII
$p = Get-Content C:\Process.txt
$p.Length
```

However, `$p.length` isn't the properties' count. Please, give me a hint how to solve this properly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Get-Process | Get-Member -MemberType Property |Measure-Object |ForEach-Object { $_.Count }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Measure-Object` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) to count the properties:

```
$propertyMeasurement = Get-Process |Get-Member -MemberType Property |Measure-Object
$propertyMeasurement.Length
```